# Perl hash metainformation

Tags: perl, hash, metadata

Is it possible to store information about a hash, in it?
And by that I mean, without adding the information to the hash in the ordinary way, which would affect keys, values etc.

Thing is I am reading a twod_array into a hash but would like to store the order within the original array without affecting how one traverses through the hash etc.

so for instance:

```
my @the_keys=keys %the_hash;
```

should not return the information about the order of the hash.

Is there a way to store meta data within a hash?

Answer (score 4):

You can store arbitrary metadata with the [`tie` mechanism](http://p3rl.org/perltie). Minimal example with a package storage that does *not* affect the standard hash interface:

```
package MetadataHash;
use Tie::Hash;
use base 'Tie::StdHash';
use Scalar::Util qw(refaddr);
our %INSERT_ORDER;
sub STORE {
    my ($h, $k, $v) = @_;
    $h->{$k} = $v;
    push @{ $INSERT_ORDER{refaddr $h} }, $k;
}
1;
```

---

```
package main;
tie my %h, 'MetadataHash';
%h = ( I => 1, n => 2, d => 3, e => 4 );
$h{x} = 5;
# %MetadataHash::INSERT_ORDER is (9042936 => ['I', 'n', 'd', 'e', 'x'])
print keys %h;
# 'enIxd'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, one can always use [Tie::Hash::Indexed](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aIndexed), I suppose:

```
use Tie::Hash::Indexed;

tie my %hash, 'Tie::Hash::Indexed';
%hash = ( I => 1, n => 2, d => 3, e => 4 );
$hash{x} = 5;

print keys %hash, "\n";    # prints 'Index'
print values %hash, "\n";  # prints '12345'
```

Comment: "`keys %the_hash` should **not** return the information about the order of the hash", no?

Comment: I suppose the OP means that we should not store ordering information inside the hash as its element, one way or another. Otherwise it makes no sense - how can we know the hash IS ordered, if not by iterating over its keys/values?

Comment: It should not return the order, no. Keys in hashes are supposed to be inherently disordered.